# Need help creating a skeleton for a client portal on DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

Total DNN noob. I can code some WebForms and MVC, but having no luck finding anything concrete out there about doing what I want in DNN

How would I go about setting up a client portal in DNN? I want to have separate areas for the client, including a main dashboard that aggregates content for the client from the other areas. The other areas would include a matter area (with matter information - some auto generated for client, other information to be input by client), a documents area, an events area, a tasks area, a communications area (for chat, or forum style questions) and a profile area for the client (contact info, invoicing, etc.).

What I'd like is for a client to login and see only their items. An admin would log in and get the same "screens" or "areas", but with aggregated content for ALL users.

I know that's a lot, but I would imagine setting me up with a way to do the overall app and then how to create the areas to navigate to would get me going. I know there are modules for each of those things out there, but a) I wouldn't know how to integrate this into one client app and b) some are cost prohibitive.

Most of what I find focuses on setting up one module. Do I go that route and set up user controls within for the different areas? Or do I create separate little modules and tie them together? This is primarily where I am stuck. I can create something like this with standalone web forms or MVC. Hooking into DNN is where I get stuck.

I appreciate any guidance / samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a LOT of questions here and many ways that you can go about doing this.  You could use third-party modules to handle this but you will need to figure out exactly which ones give you the functionality that you want.

If you are looking to do things custom, this is where it gets a lot easier.  DNN for users can manage user identity and roles.  Based on what you are saying it seems like you would have some custom modules that store all information based on UserId.  By default you only display the information for the current user.  However, if the user is in a specific role, say for example "Administrators" you would display all content.

This is pretty easy as with any DNN control that inherits from PortalModuleBase you have the UserId available to you as a property.  Then you can use UserInfo.IsInRole("Administrators") to check for admins.

Comment: I should have broken up the questions :). I'll mark as answer, but do you have any thoughts / examples of how to encapsulate that all (one module - different controls, or multiple modules?). I found something that discussed using multiviews or multiple views, but I cannot find any implementations. Thanks.